# Firebase onCreate Reference to child - Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I have successfully created and deployed cloud function for **Sending Push Notifications** on data write.

Now I am trying something a little more complex. I have implemented chat application that used to send **One-to-One** messages between users and every two users have separate **conversation Node**

```
messages
       |
       |-conversation1
       |             |-messageNode1
       |             |             |-message:abc
       |             |             |-sender:xhgdjsgghsdgj
       |             |             |-receiver: 73gfdsfghsdgfgfsd
       |             |      
       |             |+-messageNode2
       |             |+-messageNode3
       |
       |+-conversation2
       |+-conversation3
```

So if any message arrives in any of these **conversations**, A push message should be generated to **receiver** only not sender (I will implement that logic by my self).

The main problem I am facing is all **conversations** have unique keys as well as **messages** can I implement trigger for new message arrive in any conversation and get key for that conversation.

Current code for -> if any new node is added into **settings2**

```
exports.sendPush = functions.database.ref('/settings2').onWrite(event => {
    return loadUsers().then(users => {
        let tokens = [];
        for (let user of users) {
            tokens.push(user.token);
        }
        let payload = {
            notification: {
                title: 'Firebase Notification',
                body: 'This Is Message',
                sound: 'default',
                badge: '1'
            }
        };
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
    });
});
```

Comment: what is the `settings2` here?

Comment: `settings2` is another parent node i have used for testing **If a notification is sent when new data inserted into settings2** JUST FOR REFERENCE.